# jquery validation engine for timepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, timepicker

i am using jquery validation engine to check the selected time in my timepicker...

if i already selected a time and that time is already displayed in the input textbox, the validation says that the field is still emmpty and that it is required to be filled. so i tried to select a time again and after that there is no validation message showing, it worked fine..

why do i have to select a time twice?

here is the code:

```
    <div>
        START TIME:
        <div style="margin-bottom: 15px">
            <input type="text" class="validate[required]" id="inputStartTime"
                data-bind="value: inputStartTime" /> // this is initialize in my script as $('#inputStartTime').timepicker();
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: there's no value in the input field, what do you mean by "already selected a time and that time is already displayed"?

Comment: when i select a time, it is displayed in the input text that is assigned for the timepicker... however, although i already selected a time and it is showing already in the input text, the jquery validation engine still says that the field is empty and i need to select a time.... upon selecting a time again, the jquery validation engine founds no error and it sees that i already selected a time.

Comment: I see that this is an old post - but were you able to figure it out?

I'm running into same issue in my application

Answer (score 0):

You need to hide the validation engine after selected the time with

```
$('#inputStartTime').validationEngine('hide');
```